# Angular 4/5 Binding Input Field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an input field on a form as follows:

```
<mat-form-field>
                                    <input formControlName="dateFormCtrl" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" placeholder="When is your event?"
                                        (click)="picker.open()" readonly>
                                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                    <mat-datepicker touchUi="false" #picker></mat-datepicker>
                                    <mat-error>The input is required.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am using a stepper process to get through a form and I would like to know how to bind this input to the second step so they can still see what they selected and change it at a later stage. So effectively the journey is like this:

1st step: User selects date from date picker

**User presses 'Next step'**

2nd step: User sees the date they selected in the input box (it should still be editable)

Comment: By the way, you don't have to explicitly set `[touchUi]` to `false`. It should be `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind to the `(input)` event and do what you want with the selected date:

**Example:**

```
<input (input)="onDateSelect($event.target.value)"
    formControlName="dateFormCtrl" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"   
    [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" placeholder="When is your event?"
    (click)="picker.open()" readonly
>
```

The selected date will be in `$event.target.value` and you can do what you want with it inside the `onDateSelect` function, in order to use it on the next steps.